# Math Expression "generic" in Java

Tags: java, math, expression

Well, I have a math expression in a string

```
String myExpression = "2-3*(cos(x)+sen(x)-exp(-x))*(sen(2x)+1/(cos(x)))";
```

and I would like to know how to get the expression (in a string):

```
2-3*cos(x)*sen(2x)-3*cos(x)/cos(x)-3*sen(x)*sen(2x)-3*sen(x)/cos(x)+3*exp(-x)*sen(2x)+3*exp(-x)/cos(x)
```

ie, apply the distributive property, but without compute values.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there are no built-in functions that do this sort of thing. To achieve this you will most likely have to parse the string yourself and expand the expression.

Comment: Use Prolog to do this... It can be done in a few lines.

Comment: Look for a parser library for java and write a parser

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for some kind of [Java algebra system](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+algebra+system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looking to convert a mathematically expression to another form, I recommend changing it to a [**postfix/prefix expressions**](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs2121/fix.html) (< link also tells you how to convert back to 'infix') first, and then try to toy with it (you can treat your functions(eg. `sin(x)`) as constants). Hope you can do that yourself, plenty of sources to find references.

[Link to a simple Infix/Postfix Calculator](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/infix_postfix.html)
so you can try it out if you haven't tried it before.

Next, you convert back to infix, but this time distributing the multiplication and division

eg.

```
   *
  / \
 A   +
    / \
   B   /
      / \
     C   D

Infix: A*(B+C/D)
Postfix: ABCD/+*

ABCD/+*
C and D division first (distribute)                >>> C/D
B and C/D addition(addition,nothing to distribute) >>> B+C/D
A and B + C/D multiplication (distribute)          >>> A*B+A*C/D
```

So, generally speaking you do nothing but concatenate the addition and subtractions strings.
But:

1. When you have multiply by `A`  then you add a `"A*"`  string to the very beginning and after every `'+'` or `'-'`
2. When you have divide by `B`  then you add a `"/B"`  string to the very end and before every `'+'` or `'-'`.

I believe this should cover all simple expressions. You may (or may not) need a few more cases when the expression branched out extensively, haven't completely thought it through. I'll appreciate feedback.